# ASP.net form getting JS error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET form (C#) but which I click this button that should execute a JS method I get the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object"

This is odd because it should work:

```
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDriverPopulate" runat="server" Text="" Height="55px" Width="172px" CssClass="btnMTO" 
                    OnClientClick="readLicense()" ToolTip="Check Driver" />
```

textbox code here

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="DriverLast" runat="server" Width="180px" Text='<%# Eval("Last") %>' ToolTip="Enter driver last name"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <cc:TextBoxValidator ID="valDriverLast" runat="server" AllowBlank="false" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="DriverLast" ValidationGroup="ValGrpDriver"
                                        CorrectFormat="Please enter in alphanumeric characters only." FieldName="Last Name" RegString="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,\-']+$" />
```

JS function readLicense that SHOULD set the textbox's value to "hi"

```
document.getElementById("DriverLast").value = "hi";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered client id isn't necessarily the same as the server control id. You can use the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property to change this behavior.

```
document.getElementById("<%= DriverLast.ClientID %>").value = "hi";
```

Comment: Can you verify that the id in your script matches the id of the html element?

Comment: I did that and you're right! the id seems to be different when I go to my html source, I pasted the html source textbox's ID and no error!

Answer (score 2):

In the markup is there an input with the id DriverLast? ASP.NET may changed the ID of this control to it's container ID, i.e: **_ctl**_DriverLast.  Therefore you could use the `ClientId` property.

Try:

```
document.getElementById(<%=DriverLast.ClientId %>.value = "Hi";
```

Comment: Look in the markup, do you see an element with the ID DriverLast?